# OpToSoapDomComv.TRefCache.FNodes contains references to non-existing XMLNodes

Tags: delphi, soap, webservice-client

In our D2007 application we are using a Webservice, accessed with a THTTPRIO object.
When the TDatamodule containing the THTTPRIO object is Destroyed an access violation occurs.

This AV is raised when the TSoapDOMConvert is freed, which in turn executes:

```
TRefCache(RefMap[0].Instance).Free
```

calling

```
destructor TRefCache.Destroy;
begin
  FHREFs.Free;
  FMHREFs.Free;
  FNodes := nil; //Causes AV
end;
```

FNodes is a TInterfaceList containing one reference to IXMLNodes, but  the object seems to have been freed before all this.

Does anyone know this problem? How to solve it?

[Edit]More info on the usage of the RIO object
The THTTPRIO object is only used in the following call to the webservice:

```
 LIResult.Assign((Rio as IWSLicenseIntf).CheckLicense(FLicenseInfo));
```

The LIResult object is freed later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THTTPRIO has two different lifetime-management schemes. One as a Component and one as an Interface. Mixing them is a bad idea. This could be your problem.

Jean-Marie Babet commented on this here.
http://www.delphigroups.info/2/11/344722.html

The source file generated from the WSDL should have a function called GetIWSLicenseIntf (or similar). Try to use that instead of the Rio component.
Change `(Rio as IWSLicenseIntf)` to `GetIWSLicenseIntf()` and add parameters UseWSDL and URL if necessary.

Another option would be something like this

```
var
  WSLic: IWSLicenseIntf;
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil);
  RIO.URL := 'www.whatever.com';
  WSLic := RIO as IWSLicenseIntf;
  LIResult.Assign((WSLic).CheckLicense(FLicenseInfo)); 
end;
```

Interfaces in Delphi is reference counted so you should not free WSLic and not free RIO. It will be freed for you when WSLic goes out of scope.
The code is of course not tested since I do not have your code.

Comment: I tried creating and freeing the THTTPRIO component manually in code, with "THTTPRIO.Create(nil)" and "FreeAndNil(RIO)" but still I get the same AV. I edited the first post here, to show the usage of the RIO object in more detail

Comment: @Micke - comment just to notify Micke there is a respons to his comment

Comment: @micke - I don't have the function IGetWSLicenseInf() or anything alike. Found an equivalent on the net, but it does (is essence) nothing more than return (Rio as IWSLicenseIntf)

Comment: Ok. Where/how is IGetWSLicense defined? Did you create the interface yourself or or was it created for you with the WSDL importer?

Comment: @Bascy - Added a version with THTTPRIO.Create(nil). You should not free the RIO object. That is causing your exception. (Rio as IWSLicenseIntf) might seem to do nothing but in the background Rio's refcount is increased by 1. When the interface created with (Rio as IWSLicenseIntf) goes out of scope the RIO object will be freed for you which later on will cause the AV when you call FreeAndNil(Rio)

Comment: @Micke - Tried it, but when i examine the RIO object after i explicitly set WSLIC := nil the FRefcount=0 but the object still exists. So this introduces a memoryleak doesnt it?

Comment: It will not be a memory leak. The object will be freed after end. But do not take my word for it. You can test if you get memory leaks with FastMM.

Comment: I do however think that you should worry about memory leak on the return value from CheckLicense. It depends on what is returned and what you are doing in LIResult.Assign.